# Stack plot in R with large dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a relatively large dataset, which I am trying to plot into R. This is what a snippet of my dataset looks like

```
> dat
    Who      Activity Duration
1    Ch    Stationary       14
2    Ch    Stationary       18
3    Ch   Interaction        2
4    Ch    Stationary        6
5    Ch   Interaction        1
6    Ch       Display       10
7    Ch   Interaction        6
8    Ch    Stationary        5
9    Ch    Stationary       20
10   Ch    Stationary       13
11   Ch    Stationary       17
12   Co   Interaction        3
13   Co    Stationary       31
14   J    Stationary        8
15   R           OOS        1
16   R   Interaction        1
17   J           OOS        4
```

I am trying to build a stacked bar plot using the duration as a percentage, not just the raw values. So far this is what I have come up with:

```
p7 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(y= dat$Duration, x= dat$Who, fill = dat$Activity), 
           stat ="identity")
p7 <- p7 + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3")
p7 <- p7 + xlab("Chimp ID") + ylab ("Total Time Spent (min)")
p7 <- p7 + labs(fill = "Behaviour")
p7 + theme_classic()
p7 #Palette graph with percentage values
p7 + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image]

However this still does not return the bars as a total sum of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hi Sofia,

the problem is that the `scales::percent_format()`only formats the numbers with the percent sign. You need to calculate the percentages yourself before.

The code below calculates it for you.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <-  read.delim(text="id,Who,Activity,Duration
1,Ch,Stationary,14
2,Ch,Stationary,18
3,Ch,Interaction,2
4,Ch,Stationary,6
5,Ch,Interaction,1
6,Ch,Display,10
7,Ch,Interaction,6
8,Ch,Stationary,5
9,Ch,Stationary,20
10,Ch,Stationary,13
11,Ch,Stationary,17
12,Co,Interaction,3
13,Co,Stationary,31
14,J,Stationary,8
15,R,OOS,1
16,R,Interaction,1
17,J,OOS,4", sep=",")

dat <- dat%>%
  group_by(Who)%>%
  mutate(percent = Duration/sum(Duration))

p7 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(y= dat$percent, x= dat$Who, fill = dat$Activity), 
           stat ="identity")
p7 <- p7 + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3")
p7 <- p7 + xlab("Chimp ID") + ylab ("Total Time Spent (min)")
p7 <- p7 + labs(fill = "Behaviour")
p7 + theme_classic()
p7 #Palette graph with percentage values
p7 + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```